# Problems installing Wordpress on a windows server

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

It's not the first time that i install  wordpress on a linux hosting BUT this is the first time i have to do that on a windows server.

I upload the latest version on the FTP : *go to my www.mydomain.com error 500.*

okay.... maybe one file is corrupted, i re-upload them... *go to my www.mydomain.com* : error 500.

If I do : `www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php` i can enter the database information, wordpress CAN access to the DB but **it seems that there is NO** `wp-config.php` **file created**.

I absolutely don't know what to do.

Thank for your help.

(runing ofc php 5.2)

**EDIT : log file :**

```
2010-06-07 16:05:17 W3SVC17161 HEBMICROSOFT03 213.246.49.202 GET / - 80 - myIP HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+fr;+rv:1.9.2.3)+Gecko/20100401+Firefox/3.6.3 - -  500 0 0 1697 409 98
2010-06-07 16:05:19 W3SVC17161 HEBMICROSOFT03 213.246.49.202 GET / - 80 - MyIP HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+fr;+rv:1.9.2.3)+Gecko/20100401+Firefox/3.6.3 - -  500 0 0 1697 459 93
2010-06-07 16:05:19 W3SVC17161 HEBMICROSOFT03 213.246.49.202 GET / - 80 - MyIP HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+fr;+rv:1.9.2.3)+Gecko/20100401+Firefox/3.6.3 - -  500 0 0 1697 459 97
2010-06-07 16:05:20 W3SVC17161 HEBMICROSOFT03 213.246.49.202 GET / - 80 - MyIP HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+fr;+rv:1.9.2.3)+Gecko/20100401+Firefox/3.6.3 - -  500 0 0 1697 459 102
```

Comment: Have you check the rights on the files. Maybe the config.php doesn't have the read write for the IIS user.

Comment: Where there is a 500, there is always a log file somewhere telling you what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**but it seems that there is NO wp-config.php file created.**"

To work around file creation permissions, have you tried to create the wp-config.php file manually?: [Editing wp-config.php « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

Comment: could do that...or he could actually solve the root of the problem and fix his file permissions.

Comment: Windows file permissions on shared hosting are so often restrictive by the hosting company. He could solve 98% the problems he has now or will ever have in the future if he'd go back to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other domains hosted on this account?  I found that my DotNetNuke site did not play nice with WP and could not co-exist.  I ended up tossing WP and using the blog module in DNN.  Is it possible that there's some interference in using PHP with ASP.NET?

Comment: this is not a dedicaced hosting, so i think that on the server we are multiple clients

Comment: You might look into BlogEngine or another Windows blogging platform.  WP plays nice in Linux but can be a pain in Windows as others have illustrated.